Number of different arrangements of 6 letters
Find the number of ways to rescramble the word ROBLOX by reordering at least some of its letters in new orders.
I've tried 6! as an answer (720), but it doesn't work I'm assuming due to the condition: 'at least some of its letters in new orders.' I'm not quite sure if this actually is a combinatorics-permutations question since I'm simply a HS student attempting a ROBLOX game however learning apps I used suggested it was (Gauth AI)

You have two "O"'s. So, there are at most 6!/2=360 permutations, even without the condition.

First of all, you need the over-counting adjustment factor of $~\dfrac{1}{2!},~$ because two of the letters are identical.  This means that without the adjustment factor you are overcounting.  Second of all, once you accurately compute the total number of permutations, you need to subtract $~1,~$ in accordance with the problem's constraint.

BY 'the condition" I suspect that what @A.Kato is referring to is that you have to subtract 1, because at least one letter must be out of place.

@user2661923 so the condition just means that any permutation except "R O B L O X" is to be counted? im sorry it feels like stating the condition in the question is pointless

No, the problem is testing (among other things) that you realize that you have to deduct $~1~$ from what would otherwise be the final enumeration.

@user2661923 ok, so its all the permutations minus the initial configuration as thats the only one where no letter is in a new order.

yes, that's it...
